# Return all types of places and then check if selected one is an airport

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google's map api, working on a website where the user books a journey along with some waypoints.

I want to check if any of the (source; waypoints; destination) is an airport so that I can add extra functionality accordingly.

**When a user enters some string he gets suggestion list for his search and he selects a particular place. Here I want to know if he has selected an airport from the suggestion list.**

Note: I want all the places to be returned by google, just want to check if it is an airport.

```
var searchBox1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1,options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox1, "place_changed", function () {
           var place = searchBox1.getPlace();
           console.log(place.place_id);
           document.getElementById('hidden_element').value = place.place_id;
        });
```

above given is the code that gets me Place id of the selected field.
Now how know if this selected place is an airport.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @geocodezip : When a user enters some string he gets suggestion list for his search and he selects a particular place. Here I want to know if he has selected an airport from the suggestion list.

Comment: Before or after he selects the entry?

Comment: @geocodezip after he selects the entry

Comment: What issues have you encountered doing that?  What does your existing code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip I have made the required changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get exact type of the selected location. Although you can check the type of selected location using `place = searchBox1.getPlace().types;`. This will return array of place type Like :

```
var searchBox1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1,options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox1, "place_changed", function () {
       var place = searchBox1.getPlace();
       var placeType = place.types;
       console.log(placeType);              // Place type array
       document.getElementById('hidden_element').value = place.place_id;
    });
```

Hope this will help.